# Fedora 36 cannot find TTGO32 arduino board

Tags: esp32

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now. Fedora 36 cannot recognise my arduino board. Well, not correctly at least.

Arduino IDE v2 picks it up as ttyS4, but platformio only has an empty list for "pio device list".

In addition, "dmesg -w" and any other variation of it doesn't see any new USB devices, even if they do work.

I've tried installing the independent drivers to no avail. I bought a new board to make sure it's not a fried board. I also checked quite a number of USB cables, but still be problem persists.

Finally, I made sure to only use a fresh install of Fedora 36 but still no luck.

Has anyone here had similar problems before and if so any advice on how to get this sorted out? I'm currently using a laptop.

Comment: If there is *nothing* in `dmesg -w` when you plug the board in then it sounds like you're not using a proper USB data cable but a USB charger cable.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense... I'll see if I can scavange some more cables and test them as well.

Comment: It seems like I did indeed choose the wrong cable. Thank you for your help!